# How to implement context sensite help for dialogs in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have already read [Lars Vogel's tutorial on creating dynamic help in Eclipse RCP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCPHelpSystem/article.html#help_contextsensitive). However, it does not cover one topic - how to create side-pop-up help for dialog's (Like the one in screenshot) and integrate it with the rest of the help mechanism. Surprisingly, I could not find any materials describing this matter.

[image: dialog with help]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive your dialog from `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TrayDialog` to get the support for the side tray and the help button.

You may need to call the `TrayDialog` method `setHelpAvailable(true)`

You can also base your class on `TitleAreaDialog` (which extends `TrayDialog`) to get a dialog with a title and message area at the top of the dialog.